# Robot allowed the website but being identified and rejected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I need to do web scraping for a website which has allowed robot access. Below is the robot.txt file's content.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
Sitemap:https://www.sample.com/sitemap-index.xml
```

But when I try to fetch the website's content using `nokogiri`, it's being detected.

```
Nokogiri::HTML(open('https://www.sample.com/search?q=test', :ssl_verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE))
```

**Here the output:**

```
> (Document:0x3fda40e7cf70 {
  name = "document",
  children = [
    #(DTD:0x3fda40e9591c { name = "html" }),
    #(Element:0x3fda40e8c95c {
      name = "html",
      attributes = [ #(Attr:0x3fda4071a598 { name = "style", value = "height:100%" })],
      children = [
        #(Element:0x3fda3fefa28c {
          name = "head",
          children = [
            #(Element:0x3fda401a3088 {
              name = "meta",
              attributes = [ #(Attr:0x3fda40ebd7a0 { name = "name", value = "ROBOTS" }), #(Attr:0x3fda40ebd778 { name = "content", value = "NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW" })]
              }),
            #(Element:0x3fda4074faf4 {
              name = "meta",
              attributes = [ #(Attr:0x3fda3ff0beec { name = "name", value = "format-detection" }), #(Attr:0x3fda3ff0bed8 { name = "content", value = "telephone=no" })]
              }),
            #(Element:0x3fda401ca700 {
              name = "meta",
              attributes = [ #(Attr:0x3fda401c2050 { name = "name", value = "viewport" }), #(Attr:0x3fda401c217c { name = "content", value = "initial-scale=1.0" })]
              }),
            #(Element:0x3fda4079a284 {
              name = "meta",
              attributes = [ #(Attr:0x3fda4078bfb8 { name = "http-equiv", value = "X-UA-Compatible" }), #(Attr:0x3fda4078bf04 { name = "content", value = "IE=edge,chrome=1" })]
              })]
          }),
        #(Element:0x3fda407e2e6c {
          name = "body",
          attributes = [ #(Attr:0x3fda430205f0 { name = "style", value = "margin:0px;height:100%" })],
          children = [
            #(Element:0x3fda4072e2a0 {
              name = "iframe",
              attributes = [
                #(Attr:0x3fda3ff45214 {
                  name = "src",
                  value = "/_Incapsula_Resource?SWUDNSAI=28&xinfo=5-66719320-0%200NNN%20RT%281543054979096%20247%29%20q%280%20-1%20-1%20-1%29%20r%280%20-1%29%20B12%284%2c315%2c0%29%20U2&incident_id=245000650118470008-256430953704260629&edet=12&cinfo=04000000"
                  }),
                #(Attr:0x3fda3ff451d8 { name = "frameborder", value = "0" }),
                #(Attr:0x3fda3ff451b0 { name = "width", value = "100%" }),
                #(Attr:0x3fda3ff45188 { name = "height", value = "100%" }),
                #(Attr:0x3fda3ff45174 { name = "marginheight", value = "0px" }),
                #(Attr:0x3fda3ff4514c { name = "marginwidth", value = "0px" })],
              children = [ #(Text "Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: 245000650118470008-256430953704260629")]
              })]
          })]
      })]
  })
```

How can I achieve this web scraping?

Comment: Nokogiri has zero to do with robots.txt. You're issue is bypassing incapsula's DDOS protection which it's unlikely anyone here will want to help you with.

Comment: This could be caused by a whole host of things. I can only hypothesise why your request is being blocked, and how you may try to bypass it.

Comment: For example, perhaps: (1) After making too many requests, their server has blacklisted your IP. You could try using another host, or a proxy. (2) Similarly, perhaps they're throttling you. Try making fewer requests. (3) Perhaps you need to set a `user-Agent` header, or a `Cookie` header, to "trick" their server into thinking you're a human. (4) Perhaps you don't need to scrape this site in the first place. Do they have an API? .....

Comment: Assuming you do need to achieve whatever it is you're doing via web scraping, and you're not violating their terms of use, I would start by investigating what's different between your browser's web request (which presumably works), and ruby's web request - in particular, check whether you can bypass the filter with appropriate headers or a different IP.

Comment: Thanks @TomLord and pguardiario. I will try with your suggestions.